# Is std::bitset<N>::all() not mandated by C++03?

Tags: c++, std

I've recently received a bug report for my software not compiling on a MacOS platform, claiming that `std::bitset<2ul>::all` would be undefined.

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) says that `std::bitset` really has only `none()` and `any()` defined. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) claims availability of `all()`. Does anyone has an authoritative source on that? And, maybe, a good reason why two equivalent boolean operators `( none() == ! any() )` were included in the standard, but not `all()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just checked ISO/IEC 14882:2003. There is no member `all` defined in the `bitset` class template (23.3.5).

Comment: Just for completeness, C++11 adds `all`.